# Привязка данных в Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, .net, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

В приложении на Xamarin.Forms необходимо сначала получить данные с сервера, а потом используя их нарисовать FlexLayout. Я пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
public class ItemsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get
        {
            return _items;
        }
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Items"));
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Item> _items;
    public Command LoadItemsCommand { get; set; }

    public ItemsViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await LoadItems());
    }

    async Task LoadItems()
    {
        //тут загрузка с сервера
    }
```

Код страницы примерно такой:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    ItemsViewModel viewModel;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel = new ItemsViewModel();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        if (!viewModel.Items.Any())
        {
            viewModel.LoadItemsCommand.Execute(null);
        }
        this.Content = CreateFlexLayout(viewModel.Items);
    }

    private static FlexLayout CreateFlexLayout(IEnumerable<Item> Items)
    {
        //генерация layout
    }
}
```

В итоге я в дебаге вижу, что данные с сервера приходят, но страница при этом всегда пустая. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А почему не используете привязки, а в кодбихайнд городите метод `CreateFlexLayout(IEnumerable<Item> Items)` ? Вероятнее всего генерация layout происходит с пустой коллекцией айтемов. Да, и как вы наполняете `Items`? Надеюсь, с помощью `Add()` или `AddRange()` ?

Comment: @Bulson Наполняю через Add(). Почему не использую привязки - а я и не знаю, куда тут мне привязаться. Мне нужно на странице создать FlexLayout, внешний вид которого зависит от данных, что придут с сервера. Компонентов может быть 2, а может и 6, но ListView не подходит